# Low-pass filter on microcontroller output

Tags: microcontroller, audio, analog, filter

I'm producing a signal which contains 7 frequencies using a microcontroller with a DAC. the frequencies are 16.5kHz 16.7kHz 16.9kHz 17.2kHz 17.4kHz 17.6kHz 17.8kHz. and sampling frequency (at the output) is 86kHz.
The signal from the mc is at is then decreased by two resistors (600R/2600R)and fed into 
LM-386 (which increases the signal by 20) and then into a 4ohm Speaker.

Because of the generation method I get harmonics, aliasing and some parasitic low frequency of which I wish to get rid off. 
I've calculated that for RC-LPF with Fc=20kHz I need 220nF and 34ohm however, when I put them just before the the (600R/2600R) resistors the whole signal seems to be attenuated significantly!

Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks for the help!

EDIT: 
The microcontroller is pic16F1783

here's the schematic:
[image]

Comment: A schematic would be very helpful in understanding your problem.

Comment: Why are you attenuating the signal before op amp? You could just reduce op amp gain if needed. I'd put filter after op amp since op amp provides low impedance output. It would be helpful if you put a schematic and gave information about your microcontroller.

Comment: Are you using single or dual supply configuration? if it single supply, those resistors I would assume might help being the reference point, so you might have a wrong circuit. Schematic would definitively help.

Comment: It sounds like you have problems in your synthesis software.  Fixing those should make your output clean within the nyquist bandwidth, requiring only a low pass filter for anti-aliasing.

Comment: In effect, you are trying a crude workaround for the DDS implementation problems raised, but apparently not yet fixed, in your previous question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53567/frequency-shift

Comment: @Gustav; because he isn't using an op-amp.  The LM386 is a great little beast for driving 8 ohm loads at normal audio frequencies, but I'm not sure it's the best for this job; multiple full amplitude HF signals will cause a fairly high level of IMD. OTOH, I doubt that it'll be worse than an 8-bit DAC even then.

Comment: @BrianDrummond : Thanks for the clarification. I thought it was an op amp, but since it isn't Oli's explanation is good, adding a buffer is a must almost always with a DAC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PICs DAC peripheral has a very low drive capability (read high output impedance) so it needs to be buffered. The datasheet gives an example:

[image: DAC Buffer]

If you add your RC filter directly after the DAC, the impedance of he DAC will add to the R in the RC filter and lower the bandwidth. So implement the buffer and then put the filter afterwards (or you can make the filter part of the gain opamp)

To filter the opamp with the gain of 20, you can add a capacitor across the feedback resistor something like ths:

[image: Opamp Filter]

Here's a couple of references on opamp filters:

[Basic reference](http://www.physics.unlv.edu/~bill/PHYS483/op_amp_filt.pdf)
[Opamps for Everyone](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf) - not just filters, but an excellent overall free book on opamps, well worth having handy.

Comment: @Daniel - I think I have jumped the gun here, I initially though the filter was after the divider (sorry). I see the DAC is built into the PIC, just checking now...

Comment: I've looked at the PIC's datasheet, http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41579D.pdf
on page 170 which describes the DAC, it says nothing about the output impedance...

Comment: No, it's not the best documentation, but on pg.169 last paragraph it says the DAC needs buffering due to limited drive capability. So add the simple opamp buffer shown and your filter afterwards. You need to have a knwon impedaance source to drive your filter from (or as mentioned it can be made part of the opamp by placing a capacitor across the feedback resistor - if you want I can add an example of this also)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explaining what you mean by "lower the bandwidth?" which bandwidth?
If it's no trouble, I'd love to learn how to place a capacitor across the feedback resistor.
thank you very much!

Comment: The bandwidth of your circuit - e.g. what range of frequencies it will pass, and which it will block. The bandwidth is usually defined as the point at which the signal has dropped by 3dB (0.707 of the original level) Just like when you calculated your LPF, you are calculating the bandwidth of the filter.

Comment: I know what bandwidth is :) I simply didn't understand which bandwidth will be lowered... I assume you meant that instead of the bandwidth being 0-23kHz it will be lower than that? I just didn't understand why. You've helped a lot! thank you

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I think it's actually better just to put the filter after your buffer (since it simplifies things for a single supply circuit) I'll add a couple of references that go into some detail on the subject of opamp filters though.